# How to start a service living on a Windows partition

Tags: java, ntfs, services

I am developing a service on my Windows 7 / Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot machine. My service lives on an NTFS partition. It is written in Java and should work on both platforms. Just to make things clear, my Linux start script is a bash script.

fstab:

```
UUID=E24E8DDC4E8DAA3D /media/nelson/data                  ntfs   users,defaults 0 0
```

/etc/init.d/mql:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 80 Apr 14 14:15 /etc/init.d/mqld -> /media/nelson/data/linux/nelson/NetBeansProjects/CoreEngine/dist/etc/init.d/mqld*
```

But when I start my service it says:

```
sudo service mqld start
mqld: unrecognized service

sudo /etc/init.d/mqld start
sudo: unable to execute /etc/init.d/mqld: Permission denied
```

Permission denied, what permission can I be more than root?

EDIT: The point is, that an executable (here a bash script) can not be exceuted as root (permission denied). Because of the only reason that the symlink points to a file on a ntfs partition. What can I do to start services on a nfts partition - i.e. different mount options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. It is in fact a mounting option (exec). Now my fstab looks like this and it works all pretty fine.

```
UUID=E24E8DDC4E8DAA3D /media/nelson/data                  ntfs   users,defaults,exec 0 0
```